# Создание одномерного динамического массива в Java

Tags: java, массивы

Здравствуйте, написал код, который каждый элемент массива умножает на его число, но хотелось бы что бы массив был динамическим. как это реализовать? 
(В интернете смотрел. но не могу ничего толком найти)

```
package l3;

public class L3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=18;
    int arr[]=new int[n];
    System.out.print("Elementi massivu: ");
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i]=(int)Math.round(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.print(arr[i]+"; ");  
                                   }
    System.out.print("\nNovi elementi massivu: ");
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i]*(i+1);
        System.out.print(arr[i]+"; ");
                                   }
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Узнать подробнее об этой структуре данных вы можете [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128269/).

Comment: Спасибо, буду ознакамливаться